# How to get ID of Google Drive folder created with Google Script

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the following code to create a subfolder in a parent folder in Google Drive:

```
var parentfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_id);
var newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('Child Folder');
parentfolder.addFolder(newFolder);
```

I want to now get the ID of the newly created folder (Child Folder). But the variable `newFolder` returns the folder name. I've also tried setting a variable equal to `parentfolder.addFolder(newFolder)`, but that returns the name of the parentfolder. I know there's a getFoldersByName function I may be able to use to get to ID, but that seems risky as we have a lot of folders with the same name out there (we follow a consistent subfolder naming convention). The docs say it "gets a collection of all folders that are children of the current folder and have the given name," but how does it know what is the "current folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Folder.getId()` to get the Id of the newly created folder. Like this:

```
var newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('Child Folder');
Logger.log('The id of "Child Folder" is: %s', newFolder.getId() ); 
// Outputs: The id of "Child Folder" is: 0B_BaDTPJ7a-2TnFJanAtRXRzUTB
```